# Check if TabBar Item has been selected

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm new in iOS programming, I'm wondering if there is a way to use `TabBar` inside normal view instead of `UITabBarController`.

This is my scenario:

I've a `UIViewController` with a `TabBar` and a `Container`. `Container` is embedded to a `UIPageViewController` to show different pages. I made this due to easy way to control layout in storyboard. The problem is that I don't know how to use `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` function with this setup. I'm able to use it in normal `UITabBarController` but I want to force my custom view to works! This is my setup:
[Storyboard Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuY5M.jpg)

Is there a way to catch a tab item selected action with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was so simple!
Just setted `self.myTabBar.delegate = self;` and `<UITabBarDelegate>` and using `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` instead of tabBarController's one.